# Changing Comment Text Color in Text Wrangler

Tags: textwrangler

I want to change the comment text color in Text Wrangler on my MAC.  It is a faint grey that I don't like seeing.  I would like to change it to green if thats possible.  Thanks.

Answer (score 0):

You can set this in the Preferences hotkey: [⌘ ,] *(command+comma)*

You can also edit the colour schemes in the *bbcolour* files, you can find these in:

```
~/"Library/Application Support/TextWrangler/Color Schemes/"
```